# How to append unicode string to list of strings in Julia?

Tags: string, unicode, julia, list-comprehension

For integers, list comprehension can be done with:

```
julia> nums = [1,2,3,4]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> nums = [i+1 for i in nums]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

But when I tried to add a character to a string, it throws an error:

```
julia> s = split("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog")
8-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "the"  
 "lazy" 
 "fox"  
 "jumps"
 "over" 
 "the"  
 "brown"
 "dog"  

julia> s2 = [word +'X' for word in s]
ERROR: syntax: invalid comprehension syntax
```

And when the character is a private unicode char (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e000/index.htm), it throws another error:

```
julia> s2 = [word + u'\uE000' for word in s]
```

ERROR: UndefVarError: u not defined
 in collect(::Base.Generator{Array{SubString{String},1},##3#4}) at ./array.jl:307

**How to append unicode char/string to list of strings in Julia?**

Comment: In Julia, the string concatenation operator is `*`, not `+`. Additionally, it is only defined for strings, e.g., `"x"`, and not characters, e.g., `'x'`. Your last example would read `s2 = [word * "\ue000" for word in s]`.

Comment: Thanks @tim !!! But would "\ue000" recognized as a single unicode or would it be literally "\" + "e" + "000" ?

Comment: It is recognized as a single unicode character. Try `for c in s2[1] println(c) end`.

Comment: Ah, `s2[length(s2)][length(s2[length(s2)])]` -> `\ue000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quickly answer your question, the correct way is

```
[i*"X" for i in s]
```

However, please remember `'X'` is  and `"X"` are two different things.

```
julia> val = 'X'
'X'
julia> typeof(val)
Char

julia> val = "X"
"X"
julia> typeof(val)
String
```

This may happen initially if you have a Python background where there is no difference between the two.

Also string concatenation in Julia is done by `*` and not `+`!
You may ask as to why is that so! Well have a look at this post [here](http://ai.mee.nu/why_does_julia_use_for_string_concatenation)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer said, if you need to append a string you can use the string concatenation operator:

```
[word * "X" for word in s]
```

If you *really* need to concatenate a `Char`, say, because you have it in some variable `c`, it can be done using string interpolation, like so:

```
["$word$c" for word in s]
```

(Of course, you could also just convert it to a `String` with `string(c)` and use the first form.)